# Close Nautilus window automatically after drive is removed

Tags: command-line, 16.04, mount, scripts, nautilus

I remember that when using 12.04 (and maybe also 14.04) that if I removed a drive that was currently mounted and open in a Nautilus window, the window would close automatically.

Now in 16.04, the open window automatically reverts back to the media directory (`/media/{username}`) if I remove an open drive. Is there any way to restore this functionality?

Comment: I believe *"reverts back to the home directory"* isn't entirely correct. It reverts to `/media/<username>`, the dir where the drive was previously mounted. If it is different on your system, please let me know.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I've updated the question. Thanks Jacob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Patch functionality

In nautilus' Preferences, there are no options to fix it, as far as I can see; -nothing to be found in Preferences. With a tiny, extremely -low-on-juice- background script we can *patch* it however. The additional processor burden is nihil.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time

def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

curruser = os.environ["USER"]
nautpid = get(["pgrep", "nautilus"])
connected1 = [l for l in get("lsblk").splitlines() if "media" in l]
wlist1 = [l.strip() for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if nautpid in l]

t = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(1.5)
    connected2 = [l for l in get("lsblk").splitlines() if "media" in l]
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while True:
        wlist = get(["wmctrl", "-lp"])
        if wlist:
            break
    wlist2 = [l.strip() for l in wlist.splitlines() if nautpid in l]
    removed = [l for l in connected1 if not l in connected2]
    if removed:
        close = [
            w for w in wlist2 if all([
                not w in wlist1,
                any([
                    w.endswith(" "+curruser),
                    w.endswith(" Home")]),
                ])
            ]
        for w in close:
            subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ic", w.split()[0]])
    connected1 = connected2
    wlist1 = wlist2
    # periodically (re)set nautpid to fix if nautilus crashed somehow
    t += 1
    if t == 20:
        nautpid = get(["pgrep", "nautilus"])
        t = 0
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `wmctrl` to be installed

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `close_removed.py`
3. Test- run it by the command

   ```
   python3 /path/to/close_removed.py
   ```

   connect one or more drives, remove them after they were automatically mounted. Their window should close.
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/close_removed.py"
   ```

#### Explanation

- External drives are mounted in `/media/<username>/<drivename>`
- If a drive is disconnected, the corresponding `nautilus` window reverts to (at least on my system) `/media/<username>`. The *window* is therefore (re)named after the current user.
- Unfortunately we cannot simply close all `nautilus` windows, named after the current user, possible mismatches could occur. It is however safe to assume that the window that was *immediately renamed to the current user after the drive was disconnected* is the one that represented the removed drive.

That is how the script works, using:

```
pgrep nautilus
```

...on startup of the script, to get the pid of nautilus

```
wmctrl -lp
```

... to get the windows of nautilus

```
lsblk
```

...to keep an eye on possibly disconnected drives

```
wmctrl -ic <window_id>
```

...to close the targeted window(s)

#### Note

The script has a cycle of two seconds, which implies the drive needs to be attached at least two seconds for it to work.

Comment: boy had his loot!